# Run clean up code after die()

Tags: php, die

I'm working on speeding up the response time of some php code that generates html. One of the issues with the code, is that when determines a piece of information does not need to be displayed, it makes a sql call to delete the item from the database. This isn't visible to the user, and the won't be visible to the server until the next time the page is loaded, so that sql query does not need to be run as soon as the system knows that it should be run.

What I would like to do is return the response to the user, with the generated html, and then make the sql queries. I was trying this `flush` and `ob_flush`, but the page response is still not loaded until I make a call to die.

Is there anyway in PHP to run code after a call to `die()` so that the user gets their data and then I can run my database clean up code and the client is no long waiting on me to close the connection?

Comment: http://php.net/register_shutdown_function

Comment: You should completely forget about this and instead, investigate why you have to remove rows of a database when `information does not need to be displayed`

Comment: @Sebas Because this tool pulls from 7 different (sort of read only) databases and compiles all of the info onto a single page. It has it's own ordering entries for that data that does not effect the raw data databases. So if the data is removed from one of the databases, I don't find out about it until the next time my page is loaded. So when my page is loaded, I need to remove my ordering entries for data that no longer exists. And no I can't edit the code that is altering the databases to alter mine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @robbrit and @Luis Siquot. I was looking at [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and because of Luis' comment, I was reading the comments on that page, and I came across `"When using php-fpm, fastcgi_finish_request() should be used instead of register_shutdown_function() and exit()"`

which lead me to [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) which says:

`"This function flushes all response data to the client and finishes the request. This allows for time consuming tasks to be performed without leaving the connection to the client open."`

So it looks like `fastcgi_finish_request()` is what I'm looking for, not `register_shutdown_function()`

Edit: It seems that `fastcgi_finish_request()` requires another library, so instead use:

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true); // just to be safe
ob_start();
echo "The client will see this!";
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");

//Both of these flush methods must be called, otherwise strange things happen.
ob_end_flush();
flush();

echo "The client will never see this";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can register shutdown functions using [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php):

```
register_shutdown_function(function () {
    // cleanup stuff
});
```

Or in older versions of PHP:

```
function myFunc() {
  // cleanup stuff
}

register_shutdown_function("myFunc");
```

Comment: from the manual: "The shutdown callbacks are executed as the part of the request, so it's possible to send output from them and access output buffers." shutdown functions count as part of the request and will involve same time in this case

Comment: Luis is right, although the function is called after die, the buffer is not completely flushed and the connection is left open until the shutdown callback has finished executing.